# Uploading product placeholder images through Magento2 Admin fails

Tags: magento2, placeholder-image

While uploading the product placeholder images through Magento 2 Admin

System throws this error message

```
"Invalid parameter given. A valid $fileId[tmp_name] is expected".
```

I cannot find any old post on this issue here.

Any Help will appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my question hasn't been answered till now when I just could figure out what the issue was, I thought it necessary to answer my own question. All I had to do was to change the upload_tmp_dir directory to "/var/tmp" which worked for me. This change of folder has to reflect in the php.ini file. It is upto you to choose which of the allowed folders to use!